# how to hide an element after the fade out time

Tags: jquery, hide, fadeout

Say I have img element:

```
  <img id='someimage'>

  <script>
      $('#someimage').fadeOut(3000);
      $('#someimage').hide();
  </script>
```

I want to hide instruction to get executed only after the fadeOut time is over.

Comment: *But* `fadeOut()` will anyway hide the element. Why are you doing this?

Comment: fadeOut is to hide the matched elements by fading them to transparent. Why do you want to hide again? Maybe you want hide to be executed after 3000ms. Use `setTimeout` then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just check jQuery documentation ;) [[LINK]](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). Use callback as the second argument of `fadeOut()` function.

Code:

```
<script>
    $('#someimage').fadeOut(3000, function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
</script>
```

But, for the record, `fadeOut()` function will hide particular element anyway. There is no need to use `hide()` additionally for `img#someimage`.